# How to generate code for cross browser compatibility css in sublime or atom

Tags: css, sublimetext3, atom-editor

What are shortcuts and/or packages that one can use in a text editor such as Atom or Sublime, to quickly generate cross-browser compatibility CSS?

In other words, how can I generate the code below, without typing everything out:

```
.translateX {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(10px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(10px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(10px);
    -o-transform: translateX(10px);
    transform: translateX(10px); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for anyone else looking for a similar solution to automatically generate vendor-specific css prefixes, I have discovered the plugin [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer). To use with Atom (and also Sublime), I simply installed the package `'autoprefixer'`, and added the keybinding in the preferences.

https://github.com/sindresorhus/atom-autoprefixer

Answer (score 0):

I use Atom, so i'll tell you how to do it on Atom because i'm not sure for sublime, but it's probably similar.

1. Open atom and hit `CTRL + ,` or `CMD + ,` if you're on a mac.
2. Click on `Open Config Folder` option on the left.
3. Open `snippets.cson` file and add the following code:

```html
'*':
    'Translate X':
        'prefix': 'translatex'
        'body': """
            .translateX {
            -webkit-transform: translateX(10px);
            -moz-transform: translateX(10px);
            -ms-transform: translateX(10px);
            -o-transform: translateX(10px);
            transform: translateX(10px); }
        """
```

`'*'` means to apply this snippet for ALL types of files (html, css, js, php, etc).

`'Translate X'` is the name of this snippet.

`'translatex'` is the value that you have to type and hit `TAB` key so the snippet can fill everything for you.

`'body'` contains the content that this snippet holds. Keep in mind if you create single line body snippets, you can use single quotes (`''`) but if there is a multi-line body snippet like in this example, you have to put triple double quotes (`"""`).

**EDIT**:

If you want to define a snippet without default values, you can do it like so:

```html
'*':
    'Translate X':
        'prefix': 'translatex'
        'body': """
            .translateX {
            -webkit-transform: $1;
            -moz-transform: translateX($1);
            -ms-transform: translateX($1);
            -o-transform: translateX($1);
            transform: translateX($1); }
        """
```

In atom, the `$<number>` is the cursor location. In this example, it will generate the snippet with 5 cursors at the `$1` position.

If you want to have only 1 cursor, you can do:

```html
'*':
    'Translate X':
        'prefix': 'translatex'
        'body': """
            .translateX {
            -webkit-transform: $1;
            -moz-transform: translateX($2);
            -ms-transform: translateX($3);
            -o-transform: translateX($4);
            transform: translateX($5); }
        """
```

When you generate the snippet now, the default cursor location will be at `$1`. When you press `TAB`, it will loop to the position of `$2`, and so on.

**If you are using SASS:**

You can do this easily without any snippets if you are using SASS. Create a file that will hold only mixins, like this:

```css
/* Example syntax: @include transition(0.5s ease all); */
@mixin transition($arg...) {
    transition: $arg;
    -o-transition: $arg;
    -ms-transition: $arg;
    -moz-transition: $arg;
    -webkit-transition: $arg;
}

/* Example syntax: @include transform(scale(1.1, 1.1)); */
@mixin transform($arg...) {
    transform: $arg;
    -o-transform: $arg;
    -ms-transform: $arg;
    -moz-transform: $arg;
    -webkit-transform: $arg;
}

/* Example syntax: @include box-shadow(1px, 5px, 10px, rgba(0,0,0,0.5)); */
@mixin box-shadow($x, $y, $radius, $color...) {
    box-shadow: $x $y $radius $color;
    -moz-box-shadow: $x $y $radius $color;
    -webkit-box-shadow: $x $y $radius $color;
}
```

And then in other file, when you need to use it, just write:

```
.someClass {
    @include transition(0.3s ease all);
}
```

Comment: can you please confirm if this is your answer?

Comment: your answer works very well, but is not exactly what i was hoping for. also to make the snippet more generic, i would rename the prefix to `'transform'` and keep `'translateX'` blank, so that i could fill in other values. however, if i needed to generate vendor prefixes for another property, such as `'transition'`, is there a way to do that on the fly?

Comment: your answer was definitely very helpful in getting me to think towards the correct solution, and i appreciate your efforts! after some internet researching, i've discovered the autoprefixer plugin that automatically generates css snippets, and even goes as far to make verifications and updates.